# Jira Report wiith Time Remaining By Component

Tags: report, jira

When I crete a Jira issue I put it into a Component. I need to create a report to illustrate the time remaining per Component.

If I can execute a SQL query, that would be similar to:

```
Select sum (timereaming) form Issues goup by Component.
```

Is that possible with Jira?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not exactly a report to give you that. See the predefined reports available for the current version of JIRA [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Generating+Reports). There are different ways to go from here:

- Create a report on your own by using the JIRA SDK and programming a plugin (which will need a lot of time).
- Look at the existing reports and see if one of them could be used to give a similar output. Starting with for example the [Workload Pie Chart Report](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Workload+Pie+Chart+Report) and use instead of the Assignee the Component. I have no JIRA available to test it, but it should give you a similar output.
- Create a filter, and generate the table. Export from there into Excel, and groups there by component. You will see the result then in Excel only.
- Use a Dashboard and on the dashboard a gadget like [Issue Statistics Gadget](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+the+Issue+Statistics+Gadget). Use as statistic type here component as well. This should give to you a result similar to what you need.

I hope one of the tips is sufficient to give you the information you search for.